# How to open a new incognito browser instance using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

As I need to perform load testing on large number of users say 500 or 1000 so how do I run the login scenario with just 1 user login credential. As I understand if just 1 user login credential is used then only the 1st thread will be ritually logged in the other threads would actually bypass the login process and land on to the home page.
One of the solutions is to create as many users as required which is a time taking activity.
I was just wondering if there is a way to create a new incognito browser instance on JMeter for each thread such that each thread logs in by entering the credentials each time. Note that in this case we still have 1 user login credential but as we are creating  new incognito instance so the application asks for the login credential each time.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand if just 1 user login credential is used then only the 1st thread will be ritually logged in the other threads would actually bypass the login process and land on to the home page

your understanding is not correct, [JMeter Threads are **absolutely independent**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and authentication context is not passed between them so each JMeter thread will get the login page and will have to authenticate no matter of what others are doing.

It is possible to pass the authentication context to other threads using i.e. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) but by default you don't need to do anything, each thread is "incognito" as all the variables, cookies, cache, etc. are [local to each particular JMeter thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (virtual user)